# How to match all occurrences of a word without including delimiters in results

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have an input string `s="blah, blah.blah blah foöblah blah"`

Considering `whitespace`, `,` and  `.` as delimiters I want to match all whole word occurrences of blah e.g. after replacing desired match with `x` above string should look like `x, x.x x foöblah x`

I tried following Regex
`/(?:\s|.|,|^)blah(?=\s|.|,|$)/g` but it has following problems

1. It is matching against `blah` in `foöblah`
2. It is including matching against surrounding delimiters, which is not desired. **I only want the blah**

**EDIT#1** : input string `s` can have accented characters so using word boundaries as regex will not work.

Comment: Why don't you simply replace `/\bblah\b/` with `x`

Comment: forgot to mention: i may also have accented characters  in my input string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [word boundary `\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters_to_verify_input)

> Matches a word boundary. A word boundary matches the position where a word character is not followed or preceeded by another word-character. Note that a matched word boundary is not included in the match. In other words, the length of a matched word boundary is zero. (Not to be confused with [\b].)
>
> Examples:
>   /\bm/ matches the 'm' in "moon" ;
>   /oo\b/ does not match the 'oo' in "moon", because 'oo' is followed by 'n' which is a word character;
>   /oon\b/ matches the 'oon' in "moon", because 'oon' is the end of the string, thus not followed by a word character;
>   /\w\b\w/ will never match anything, because a word character can never be followed by both a non-word and a word character.(*[Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters_to_verify_input)*)

```js
s = "blah, blah.blah blah fooblah blah";
console.log(
  s.replace(/\bblah\b/g, 'x')
)
```

---

**UPDATE :**

With your own regex you need to escape `.` by `\.`  and while replacing add captured group value with string using `$1`
**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sT1/1)**

```js
s = "blah, blah.blah blah fooblah blah";
console.log(
  s.replace(/(\s|\.|,|^)blah(?=\s|\.|,|$)/g, '$1x')
)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I might have accented characters like à,é etc in my input string. So word boundaries may not work

Comment: @user3733345 : check second snippet

Comment: I understood the need to escape `.` It prevents false matches. But I don't follow `$1x` thing here. How is it working here?

Comment: @user3733345 `$1` refers to the first captured group

Comment: first captured group in this case is `blah` ...right?  And you are replacing every match with `blahx`. Then how come I am getting only x's in result? What am I missing here

Comment: @user3733345 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: @user3733345 : captured group here is `(\s|\.|,|^)`

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `/\bblah\b/` with `x`.

```js
document.writeln('blah, blah.blah blah fooblah blah'.replace(/\bblah\b/g, 'x'));
```

The `\b` ensures it's the beginning *or* the end of the word.

**Edit:**

If you use

```
(^|[^\w\x80-\xff])blah(?![\w\x80-\xff])
```

and replace with

```
$1x
```

I believe you'll get what you want.

```js
document.writeln('blah, blah.blah blah! foöblah blah éblah'.replace(/(^|[^\w\x80-\xff])blah(?![\w\x80-\xff])/g, '$1x'));
```

It's similar to Pranav's solution but will handle all punctuations, e.g. `blah!`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I might have accented characters like à,é etc in my input string. So word boundaries may not work

Comment: It wont because javascript will detect word boundary in `foöblah` after `ö`